# Itemize clone for headers in table

Tags: macros, xparse

I'd like to define a command called `\headers` that takes an undefined number of parameters.

e.g. `\headers{Category One}{Category Two}{Category Three}`

And it would output the following:

```
\textbf{\textit{Category One}} & 
\textbf{\textit{Category Two}} &
\textbf{\textit{Category Three}} \\
\hline
\hline
```

The idea is to use this inside a custom tabularx package I've used, so I could just go:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{XXX}
    \headers{Category One}{Category Two}{Category Three}
\end{tabularx}
```

How could I achieve something like this? I saw a lot about `xparse` and `\clist_map_inline:nn` but none of that would allow the `&` character to join any parameter after the first.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Would a LuaLaTeX-based solution be acceptable, or are you restricted to using pdfLaTeX?

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: @Andrew Weird. I did use the back-ticks, but maybe I did something wrong. I'll use the `{}` next time! Thank you!

Comment: @Mico I am afraid I dont know the difference of the two. I do need to export to PDF at the end.

Comment: @Extremo Back-ticks are fine for in-line text but it is better to index the code four spaces when you insert *blocks* of code.

Comment: @Andrew Ah that makes sense! I probably forgot that part! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get output like:

[image]

with the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
  \makeatletter
\newcommand\headers[1]{%
  \def\sep{}%
  \def\realheader{}%
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\protected@xappto\realheader{\sep\textbf{\textit{##1}}}\xdef\sep{&}}
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  \\\toprule\realheader\\\midrule
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{XXX}
  \headers{Category one, Category two, Category three}
  stuff & stuff & stuff\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Rather than using `\hline` I have succumbed to my biases and used the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package as I think this gives much better output.

Apart from using [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) the main change from the OP is that I have changed the syntax to use a command separated list for the header, which is then turned into the table header using `\docsvlist` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. Unfortunately, this seems to require a little bit of expansion trickery using `\protected@xappto` to construct the header piece by piece.

**EDIT**

Here is a fancier version that defines a new table environment `mytable` that takes one argument that specifies the column headers as a comma separated list, and where body of the environment contains the (tabularx) environment. Using this the code:

```
\begin{mytable}{Category one, Category two, Category three}
  stuff & stuff & stuff\\
\end{mytable}
```

produces

[image]

which is essentially the same as above except that I have used the OPs formatting. The main advantage of this approach is that you do not have the specify the column headers so that, for example,

```
\begin{mytable}{Category one, Category two, Category three, Column four}
  stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff\\
\end{mytable}
```

works as expected.

Here is the modified code (see the comments for an explanation of what the code is doing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{mytablecolumns}% to automate the number of columns
\newenvironment{mytable}[1]{%
  \def\sep{}% will be the table column separator
  \setcounter{mytablecolumns}{0}% reset column counter
  \def\realheader{}% will become the table header
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{% construct each entry in the header
    \protected@xappto\realheader{\sep\textbf{\textit{##1}}}% add header
    \stepcounter{mytablecolumns}% increment column counter
    \xdef\sep{&}% set up next column separator
  }
  \docsvlist{#1}% create the table header
  \xdef\sep{*{\arabic{mytablecolumns}}X}% create the table specifications
  \expandafter\tabularx\expandafter\hsize\expandafter{\sep}% start tabularx
  \realheader\\\hline\hline% insert header and two \hlines
  }{\endtabularx}% end tabularx environment
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mytable}{Category one, Category two, Category three}
  stuff & stuff & stuff\\
\end{mytable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in my custom tabularx. Could you explain what you're actually doing there? Maybe I can then replicate something similiar.

Comment: I got it to work using the following
`
    \newcommand{\headers}[1]
    {
        \renewcommand*\do[1]{\textbf{\textit{##1}} &}
        \docsvlist{##1}
    \hline
    \hline
    }
`
Thanks for your help and finding the package!

Comment: @Extremo See my edit for a fancier version

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Note that it loads the `booktabs` package and employs `\midrule` instead of `\hline\hline`.

All of the actual work is performed by the Lua function called `headers`, which employs Lua's powerful `string.gsub` function. The `headers` function is assigned to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, which operates at very early stage, *before* TeX starts its usual macro expansion work.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
-- start of Lua code
function headers ( s )
  if string.find ( s , "^%s-\\headers" ) then
    s = s:gsub ( "%b{}" , "&\\textbf{\\textit%0}" )
    s = s:gsub ( "\\headers&" , "" ) .. "\\\\ \\midrule"
  end
  return s
end
-- end of Lua code
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% assign 'headers' function to LuaTeX's 'process_input_buffer' callback
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
  "process_input_buffer",headers,"headers")}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
  \toprule
  \headers{Category One}{Category Two}{Category Three} 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```